# Have haystack-0.42 installed in PyCharm project and getting error: No module named 'haystack.telemetry', haystack.telemetry import tutorial_running

Tags: pycharm, telemetry, haystack

#### From PyCharm IDE (but runs fine from command line):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "\~/PycharmProjects/RobertaQA/test1.py", line 3, in \<module\>

from haystack.telemetry import tutorial_running

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'haystack.telemetry'
```

Comment: It just means you did not install `haystack` library.

Comment: I've installed haystack (0.42), but there is no listing for telemetry in venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/haystack.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to go to (Pycharm) Setting//Python Interpreter and add (+) four packages:

farm-haystack,
torch,
nltk, and
sentence-transformers.

(Previously, was adding "haystack", which was incorrect.)